# What is a faster way to truncate a group of tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, rename, truncate

I’m using MySql 5.5.37.  I’m trying to truncate data from a group of tables.  I read here -- [Quickest way to delete enormous MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879327/quickest-way-to-delete-enormous-mysql-table), that re-creating/renaming the tables was supposedly faster, but I’m getting errors …

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
…
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_organization LIKE organization; 
RENAME TABLE organization TO old_t, new_organization TO organization; 
DROP TABLE old_t;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_organization_address LIKE organization_address; 
RENAME TABLE organization_address TO old_t, new_organization_address TO organization_address; 

ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './sbjunit_ebook/organization_address' to './sbjunit_ebook/old_t' (errno: 150)
```

Looking further into the problem, it says …

```
Error in foreign key constraint of table sbjunit_ebook/old_t:
there is no index in referenced table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "FK1_ORGANIZTION_ADDRESS" FOREIGN KEY ("ORGANIZATION_ID") REFERENCES "old_t" ("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
The index in the foreign key in table is "UK_ORGANIZATION_ADDRESS"
```

Why is renaming the tables not updating the foreign key references and what is a faster way to truncate data from a group of tables?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a table (using the `RENAME TABLE` statement) doesn't affect the foreign keys referencing the table. The foreign keys that reference the table get "updated" only in the sense that they are unaffected, they aren't "lost". Only the name of the table is affected; the foreign key references referring to the table aren't lost.

When you disable foreign_key_checks, you are essentially telling the database that you are taking on responsibility for maintaining the integrity of the data. It doesn't instruct MySQL to "lose" foreign key constraint definitions when tables are renamed.

In this case, when the table named `old_t` is dropped, MySQL assumes that a table named `old_t` will be recreated, and that it will have a suitable index (column names, column datatypes) that the existing foreign keys will reference. It's also assuming that  appropriate rows will be inserted so that all of the foreign key constraints will be satisfied.

(Note that the `DROP TABLE` statement would not have succeeded if FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS was enabled, the statement would have returned an error.)

---

The fastest way to empty that table would actually be to disable the foreign key constraints that reference the table, and then perform a `TRUNCATE` statement on the table. MySQL will actually perform the TRUNCATE operation (under the covers) by creating a new empty table, and dropping the old table.

You could follow the same pattern for other tables.

At that point, you would re-enable the the foreign key constraints.

(MySQL doesn't actually support DISABLE/ENABLE of foreign key constraints; we have to DROP and ADD the foreign key constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE bar DROP 
 FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) ;

ALTER TABLE bar ADD 
  CONSTRAINT FK_bar_foo 
  FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo (id) ;
```

(Note that creating a foreign key constraint on "large" tables can take a bit of time, but if table `bar` is empty, it will be really fast.)

---

**UPDATE**

The `information_schema` tables can be queried to help build the `DROP` and `ADD` of the foreign keys.

It's important to "save off" the existing foreign key constraints before dropping them.

This SQL statement works for generating statements to `DROP` and `ADD`  of foreign key constraints on some of my tables. (All of my foreign key constraints have user supplied names, no system generated names.) Your mileage may vary:

For foreign keys referencing **`mydatabase.mytable`**

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',r.constraint_schema,'`.`',r.table_name
             ,'` ADD'
             ,' CONSTRAINT `',r.constraint_name,'`'
             ,' FOREIGN KEY ('
             ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`',k.column_name,'`') 
                           ORDER BY k.ordinal_position)
             ,') REFERENCES ',r.referenced_table_name
             ,' ('
             ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`',k.referenced_column_name,'`')
                           ORDER BY k.ordinal_position)
             ,')'
             ,' ON UPDATE ',r.update_rule
             ,' ON DELETE ',r.delete_rule
             ,';'
       ) AS add_fk
     , CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',r.constraint_schema,'`.`',r.table_name
              ,'` DROP FOREIGN KEY '
              ,'`',r.constraint_name,'`'
              ,';'
       ) AS drop_fk
  FROM information_schema.referential_constraints r
  JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
       ON k.constraint_schema = r.constraint_schema 
       AND k.table_name  = r.table_name
       AND k.constraint_name = r.constraint_name
 WHERE r.constraint_schema = 'mydatabase'
   AND r.referenced_table_name = 'mytable'
 GROUP BY r.constraint_schema, r.table_name, r.constraint_name ;
```

Comment: I'm trying to see if there's a better way to truncate tables other than saying "truncate table t", but in your answer you're saying to actually use the "truncate" statement to clear out data?  Am I misreading what you're suggesting?

Comment: @Dave: Yes, TRUNCATE is the fastest, if there are no foreign key constraints referencing the table. When there are no foreign key constraints, it's equivalent to dropping the existing table and creating a new empty table.

Comment: Sounds good.  My script that truncates all tables is auto-generated so I need to figure out a way to drop and re-create the foreign keys.  Then I can run a speed test against what I ahve now, and then I'll come back and accept.

Comment: @Dave: I added a query againast `information_schema` that helps extract the foreign keys that reference a particular table. This does work to identify foreign keys that reference some of my tables (MySQL 5.5); I can't guarantee that it will it work for you. This only identifies the FK constraints, and takes a stab at generating SQL that will drop and re-add them. I save off the 'ADD' statements before I run the drop, so I can re-create them later. (In Oracle, I don't have to drop the constraints; I can just DISABLE them and leave the definitions intact.)

Comment: Hi, An update to what I discovered and also to verify I tried your suggestion correctly.  I had two scripts -- the first I SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; at the beginning, executed truncate_table tbl against all tables and then SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;.  The other I SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; disabled all foreign key checks using your query, ran truncate_table tbl against all tables, re-enabled all foreign key constraints and SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;.  The second script ran 10 times slower than the first, so disabling/re-enabling foreign keys didn't help me, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Dave: When there aren't any foreign key constraints referencing a table (InnoDB), the `TRUNCATE` operation creates a new empty table, which is relatively fast (we use the `innodb_file_per_table` option, so MySQL doesn't have to reclaim any free space in the tablespace, it can just get rid of the old .idb file for the table. When there are foreign keys referencing a table, the `TRUNCATE` operates more slowly, using a `DELETE`. (Sounds as if setting foreign_key_checks does the same thing.) Creating foreign key constraints on empty tables should be very fast.