# TRUNCATE v/s DROP

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am reading DBMS concepts and i have some confusion about `TRUNCATE` and `DROP`. I know `TRUNCATE` does not affect structure, but what are other differences? When its better to use `TRUNCATE` and when `DROP` is better?

In some website it is written that truncate is faster but no one explained why.

Comment: Drop will delete all, like you clear your hard disk. Truncate it is “like” delete from tablename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lots of information available on the difference of both ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135653/difference-between-drop-table-and-truncate-table)). However for the second part of your question regarding the performance - you should not worry that much for truncate vs drop. The reason being is it's more about the functionality you are expecting from truncate vs drop. You 'drop' when you don't intend to use the table anymore. You 'truncate' when you just want the table definition intact , you just want to delete the table data fast. The perceived difference in performance may come from the  implementation details ( which can sometime be a bug like [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68184)) in the database.

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNCATE` removes all the *contents* of the table, but keeps the structure of the table intact.  Besides data, tables have indexes, constraints, triggers, and partitions for instance.

`DROP` drops the tables and the associated metadata, including indexes, constraints, and triggers.

You use `TRUNCATE` when you want to reload the table with new data.  You use `DROP` when you don't want the table anymore.

A third possibility is `DELETE` to remove all the rows.  Although the end result is the same as `TRUNCATE`, In most databases, this logs every row deletion and triggers delete triggers, so it is more expensive than `TRUNCATE`.